# EntityManager merge() causes duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I'm getting some very odd behavior with `EntityManager.merge()`. Here's what is happening. I have a REST API setup with Spring MVC, Hibernate, and JPA to insert, update, and delete items from a MySQL database. Both the insert and update functions use `EntityManager.merge()`, and they both work fine 99% of the time.

However, at one point, which seems to be first call to update the record, it creates a duplicate of the record in the database, and then goes back to the original record and makes changes to it like it should.

I'm really at a loss for why this is happening. You would think that if it created a duplicate record it would edit that one, but nope, on update it creates the duplicate, abandons it, and goes back to the first record to make changes.

I was thinking it's because of how I have my hashcode and equals setup in my entity beans, which it could be. Though I don't see anything wrong with them since I've based them off of unique keys, not the ID.

My code is below. Any ideas on what is going on would be a big help.

Here's the entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DAY_ITEM")
public class DayItem implements GtEntity, Serializable{
    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal amount;
    private Integer modId;
    private Integer fmOrder;
    private String modName;
    private Date daysDate;
    private String daysDateString;
    private Long foodId;
    private Long mealId;
    private FoodItem foodItem;
    private MealItem mealItem;
    private ArrayList<FoodItem> foodItems;
    private ArrayList<MealItem> mealItems;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "EMAIL", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = true, length = 100)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "AMOUNT", nullable = true)
    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "MOD_ID", nullable = false)
    public Integer getModId() {
        return modId;
    }

    public void setModId(Integer modId) {
        this.modId = modId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "FM_ORDER", nullable = false)
    public Integer getFmOrder() {
        return fmOrder;
    }

    public void setFmOrder(Integer fmOrder) {
        this.fmOrder = fmOrder;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "MOD_NAME", nullable = true, length = 50)
    public String getModName() {
        return modName;
    }

    public void setModName(String modName) {
        this.modName = modName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "DAYS_DATE", nullable = false)
    public Date getDaysDate() {
        return daysDate;
    }

    public void setDaysDate(Date daysDate) {
        this.daysDate = daysDate;
    }

    @Transient
    public String getDaysDateString() {
        if(daysDateString == null) {
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            return formatter.format(daysDate);
        }
        return daysDateString;
    }

    public void setDaysDateString(String daysDateString) {
        this.daysDateString = daysDateString;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "FOOD_ID", nullable = true)
    public Long getFoodId() {
        return foodId;
    }

    public void setFoodId(Long foodId) {
        this.foodId = foodId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "MEAL_ID", nullable = true)
    public Long getMealId() {
        return mealId;
    }

    public void setMealId(Long mealId) {
        this.mealId = mealId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FOOD_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID",
            updatable = false, insertable = false)
    public FoodItem getFoodItem() {
        return foodItem;
    }

    public void setFoodItem(FoodItem foodItem) {
        this.foodItem = foodItem;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MEAL_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID",
            updatable = false, insertable = false)
    public MealItem getMealItem() {
        return mealItem;
    }

    public void setMealItem(MealItem mealItem) {
        this.mealItem = mealItem;
    }

    @Transient
    public ArrayList<FoodItem> getFoodItems() {
        return foodItems;
    }

    public void setFoodItems(ArrayList<FoodItem> foodItems) {
        this.foodItems = foodItems;
    }

    @Transient
    public ArrayList<MealItem> getMealItems() {
        return mealItems;
    }

    public void setMealItems(ArrayList<MealItem> mealItems) {
        this.mealItems = mealItems;
    }

    public void makeDaysDate() throws ParseException{
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        this.daysDate = new Date(formatter.parse(this.daysDateString).getTime());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof DayItem)) return false;

        DayItem dayItem = (DayItem) o;

        if (!getEmail().equals(dayItem.getEmail())) return false;
        if (!getModId().equals(dayItem.getModId())) return false;
        if (!getFmOrder().equals(dayItem.getFmOrder())) return false;
        if (!getDaysDateString().equals(dayItem.getDaysDateString())) return false;
        if (getFoodId() != null ? !getFoodId().equals(dayItem.getFoodId()) : dayItem.getFoodId() != null) return false;
        return getMealId() != null ? getMealId().equals(dayItem.getMealId()) : dayItem.getMealId() == null;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = getEmail().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + getModId().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + getFmOrder().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + getDaysDateString().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + (getFoodId() != null ? getFoodId().hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (getMealId() != null ? getMealId().hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here's the code doing the initial create:

```
@Override
public List<DayItem> saveDayItem(DayItem item) throws Exception {
    EntityManager manager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = manager.getTransaction();
    List<DayItem> results = null;
    try {
        tx.begin();
        manager.merge(item);
        manager.flush();
        manager.clear();
        results = findUserDay(item.getDaysDate(), item.getEmail(), manager);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tx.rollback();
        throw e;
    } finally {
        manager.close();
        return results;
    }
}
```

Here's the code doing the update:

```
public <T extends GtEntity> T store(T entity) throws Exception {
    T managedEntity = null;
    EntityManager manager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = manager.getTransaction();
    try{
        tx.begin();
        managedEntity = manager.merge(entity);
        tx.commit();
    }catch(RuntimeException e){
        tx.rollback();
        throw e;
    }finally {
        manager.close();
        return managedEntity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the entity has ID when updating?

Comment: @DanielJipa Yes it has the same ID as the original record.

Answer (score 0):

Since you implemented `equals` and `hasCode`, Hibernate will use those methods to find the entity to be updated. Assuming the detached object has been changed, `equals` and `hasCode` will never return the same value as the attached entity, therefore Hibernate will assume it is a new instance.

You should read the hibernate doc about [`equals` and `hasCode`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-model-pojo-equalshashcode).

Comment: After careful debugging I have determined that this is not the problem. Every time the update function is run `EntityManager.contains()` returns false for the entity I pass it, meaning that it is not in the persistence context. It returns false every single time, but it only creates a duplicate once. So there is something else going on.

Comment: Change your equals and hashCode implementation to use only the Id

Comment: @DanielJipa I used `EntityManager.find()` which takes the class of the entity it will lookup at its id. At one of the calls to the update function it returns null value. Meaning it couldnt find it. Only on one of the calls though. And it's always at the same point, its when the amount field of the DayItem equals 1.02. It's always 1.02, no other number causes the DayItem to be duplicated. I'm really at a loss.

Comment: @Graham `EntityManager.contains()` will use `equals` and `hashCode` to determine whether the entity is loaded in the context or not. If you change one field of the entity and submit it to `merge()`, `EntityManager.contains()` will always return false, because the field changed.

Comment: By the way, when you said "one of the calls", you mean sequencial calls or concurrent ones?

Comment: @DiogoSantana it's a Web application so the calls could end up being concurrent. But for now, since I'm the only one using it, they are sequencial.

Comment: I solved the problem, and it ended up being my unique key. For some reason, I think since updates were happening asynchronously, data was getting mixed and matched on the same records and then committed. By limiting my unique key to email, mod_id, fm_order, and days_date, this fixed the problem. Before my unique key included the fields above plus amount, food_id, and meal_id. And on the duplicate records the food_id was different. I still don't understand why this was happening. But it's fixed.